# Spring Data - no property found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {
...
    @Column(name = "isVisibleForSender")
    private boolean isVisibleForSender;
}
```

and Spring Data repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface MessageCRUDRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
...
    public boolean getVisibleForRecipient(boolean isVisibleForRecipient);
}
```

When compiling, the program throws me an exception **Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getIsVisibleForRecipient found for type Message!**

Comment: What are you trying to do with you interface method getVisibleForRecipient? aka what data do you expect to be returned when you call that method?

Comment: In entity User is @OneToMany(...)  private List<Message> receivedMessages; And I want to get to the message list that have set isVisibleFoRecipient = true;

Comment: From what you have posted there is no boolean value VisibleForRecipient. Is that not posted?

Comment: I got lost and I have no idea how to do it. I just want to retrieve the messages that have the isVisibleForRecipient field set to true.

Comment: Yes but from what you posted there is no isVisibleForRecipient in your message object. The reason you are getting that error is because you have named your method wrong OR that the isVisibleForRecipient field does not actually exists in the Message object

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your comments, you have the wrong method name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {

    @Column(name = "isVisibleForRecipient")
    private boolean visibleForRecipient;

}
```

And for the repo:

```
interface MessageCRUDRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
   List<Message> findByVisibleForRecipient(Boolean bool);
}
```

Make sure you have getters and setters for the visibleForRecipient field in the message object

Comment: I mean, when I download a user, and with his message it automatically retrieves the messages that have the isVisibleForRecipient set to true. https://pastebin.com/VbQmAcZU

Comment: Where is isVisibleForRecipient defined? Please post where it is defined

Comment: Just edited my answer to match what you linked.  Please update your post to the same as what you linked.  Also there is good documentation located here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ on